# windows 7 dhcp (as server) on interface

Tags: windows, dhcp

I have a USB to ETH converter which I want to connect to a device that needs DHCP. How can I convince windows to act like a DHCP server for that interface?

Providing IP for device that I can later bind in windows browser.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Get a freeware, like https://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcpserver/

Comment: Google 'internet connection sharing windows 7'

Comment: @yagmoth555 thanks, that did the trick! Appreciate.

Comment: glad to know it worked :) will write as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a freeware, like [sourceforge.net/projects/dhcpserver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dhcpserver)

I often use that kind of software from time to time to setup a LAB at my desk when I don't want to impact a real environment in production, but atleast the gear got configured with the real IP/or I can atleast connect to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have a domain controller doing DHCP just setup the router you're connecting the device to to serve DHCP.

Comment: I don't have a router, just a USB to ETH adapter. I'm on a trip so I don't want to buy a router for this.